# How to use datadriven test within @BeforeClass method in TestNG framework

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

Want to take urls one by one at `@BeforeClass` method and perform action in different `@Test` methods.

But `@dataProvider` only can used along with `@Test` method not with `@BeforeClass`  in `TestNG`

constraint:-

- Actually, All `@Test` method are independent on each other and So cant use single test method.
- urls in `@dataProvider` is always be changing. We gets urls in run-time

How could we manage such scenarios ?

In short architecture of framework:-

```
     @BeforeClass(dataProvider = "getTestUrls") 
        public void testPage(){
            driver.get(testUrls);
       }

      @Test(priority=1)
      @Test(priority=2)

     @DataProvider
        public Object [][] getTestUrls(){
            return new Object[][]   { { 1,"http://www.yahoo.com" }, {2,"http://www.google.com" } };
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Factory method with dataProvider method  , 
It create a multiple instance.

```
 @Factory(dataProvider = "getUrls")
        public SEOErrorFactoryResetBeforeClass(String pagUrl) {
            this.pagUrl = pagUrl;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

These constraints can be overcome by using data driven framework using POI jar files.
You can fetch the test urls from a excel file, data provider have some limitations.

Comment: Fetching is data from excel or array is of same thing. But the my concern here is use of "dataProvider" in "Beforeclass" or "BeforeTest" method

Answer (score 0):

Yes , @Factory annotation will solved your concern

```
@Factory(dataProvider = "getUrls")
        public SEOErrorFactoryResetBeforeClass(String pagUrl) {
            this.pagUrl = pagUrl;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

> context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameters();

like this:

```
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @BeforeClass
  public void setUp(ITestContext context) {
  System.out.println(context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameters());    

  }
```